# Dynamic TextView In Dynamic TableRow with marquee effect to textview in android

Tags: android, marquee

I am developing one app where i am displaying some data in table format.so i implemented following code

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {split1=new String[split.length];
        split2=new String[split.length];
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
        for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++)
        {

            String aa=split[i];
            String [] aaa=aa.split(" : ");
            split1[i]=aaa[0];
            split2[i]=aaa[1];
            TableRow row=new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            TableLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                    new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            lp.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
            row.setLayoutParams(lp);
            TextView tvDebt=new TextView(OfferItemView.this);
            TextView tv=new TextView(OfferItemView.this);
            tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);

            tv.setSingleLine(true);
            tv.setSelected(true);
            Log.v("Detail",""+split2[i]);
            tvDebt.setText("" + split1[i]);
            tv.setText("  :  " + split2[i]);
            row.addView(tvDebt);
            row.addView(tv);
            table.addView(row);
        }
    }
```

It display data but the if one of the string is large then that text go out of screen.i want to apply merquee effect if string is large..

I am adding the screenshot of that tablelayout

[See the text go out of the screen size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giTMF.png)

so i want to display marquee effect to it

Please give solution to me because from last 2 months i didnt get solution

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Have you considered placing the text view within a scroll view? This would make it so the text stays the same size as the other text, and you could write a line as long as you want.

Comment: But i want marquee effect on that textview

Comment: Please sir help me i am frustrated now

Comment: ok. I just tested some code. I'll post the answer soon

Answer (score 0):

You will probably like this solution more. You will have to do minimal modifications to make it work with your existing code. The problem you had is due to the order you set the text view attributes I believe. Set the attributes in the order I have in the below example to get the marquee effect.

```
TableLayout tableLayout;


private void marquee() {
    tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);

    TextView textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    TextView textView2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

    //the order in which you set the properties of the text view is important
    //this order works
    textView1.setText("Some long garbage bla bla bla barf narf laf tarf marf garf yarf parf");
    textView1.setTextSize(25);
    textView1.setWidth(100);
    textView1.setHeight(150);
    textView1.setLines(1);
    textView1.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    textView1.isFocusableInTouchMode();
    textView1.isFocusable();
    textView1.setSelected(true);
    textView1.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    textView1.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);

    //I show that you can apply the effect on more than 1 text view
    textView2.setText("Some long garbage bla bla bla barf narf laf tarf marf garf yarf parf");
    textView2.setTextSize(25);
    textView2.setWidth(100);
    textView2.setHeight(150);
    textView2.setLines(1);
    textView2.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    textView2.isFocusableInTouchMode();
    textView2.isFocusable();
    textView2.setSelected(true);
    textView2.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    textView2.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);

    //create row
    TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    TableLayout.LayoutParams lp =
            new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);

    //add the text views to the row 
    row.addView(textView1);
    row.addView(textView2);

    //add the row to the table
    tableLayout.addView(row);


}
```

Comment: I didnt get it how to do it

Comment: ok, I'm a bit busy. I gave a fast solution. I will come back and write a better solution in a few hours

Comment: I am waiting for your replay sir please

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: @Abhijit I made an edit. The above solution will require only minimal modification.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for giving me a valuable time for me

Comment: Sir its working but the width of textview is very small.I want to give universal width that is fit to screen

Comment: for the setText, setTextSize, setWidth, and setHeight method calls you should not use hard coded values as I have done, I only used them to make the example more simple. You should calculate the the required value for each method based on your needs.

Comment: @Abhijit, I would like to point out that proper practice is to mark the answer as correct, in-order to have proper page documentation.

Comment: Just add @holycatcrusher to the comments, but I think the reason nobody helps you is because you don't mark answers as correct once they are solved.